# Using an object as a model to avoid too many parameters - XNA/C#

Tags: xna, c#, oop

I have 3 classes(Skill,Projectile and Status),Skill has Projectile and Projectile has Status, all of them need to read information from a txt and to avoid open it everytime I want to create an object I want to read all the txt on Skill and pass the information Projectile need as arguments and then on Projectile create Status passing the information needed as arguments too

As Projectile going to create a lot of Status objects it need to receive Projectile's informations and Status's informations from Skill, to avoid too many parameters can I create a Status object on Skill and pass it to Projectile and everytime I need to create another status I use the first one as a model?

As example:

```
 public class Skill
{
  String skillName,projectileName,statusName;
  int    skillNumber,projectileNumber,statusNumber;
  public Skill(){
      //Code to read txt and fill variables

      //What is happening
      Projectile projec = new Projectile(projectileName,statusName,projectileNumber,statusNumber);

      //To avoid above
      Status status = new Status(statusName,statusNumber);
      Projectile projec = new Projectile(projectileName,projectileNumber,status);

  }
}
```

And then at Projectile

```
public class Projectile
{
  //Constructor,variables and methods

  //Method that create Status
   public void Update(){
         if(hitEntity){
          //this status was received from Skills
          Status tempStatus = new Status(status.statusName,status.statusNumber);
          }     
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good practice. Other than for data collection, you are much better off practicing the design and use of immutable objects. This may feel unnatural at first, but will immensely ease reasoning about your object/application state as your application grows.

Comment: And, if you are de-serializing text content, learn and use the built-in de-serializing mechanisms.